# Adding a Custom Attribute to a DocuSign Envelope

Tags: vb.net, controller, docusignapi

### The Question:

How do I add a custom attribute like `user_id` to a DocuSign envelope, so that when I receive the callback from DocuSign, I can retrieve the associated `user_id`?  (In VB.Net)

I've read the documentation about [Custom Fields](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Add%20Envelope%20Custom%20Fields%20to%20an%20Envelope.htm), though this seems like I'd create them on my template in the Admin Panel - I'd rather create them dynamically in the code, if possible. Nonetheless, I've attempted to use this method (unsuccessfully). The code is included below.

---

### What I've Tried

**Setting the EnvelopeID manually:**

```
envDef.EnvelopeId = app_Id
```

The EnvelopID gets overwritten by DocuSign's auto-generated GUID

**Creating a Custom Field:**

*(After creating a Text CustomField named `User_ID` in the admin panel...)*

```
Dim user_id_field As New TextCustomField()
user_id_field.Name = "User_ID"
user_id_field.Value = user_id

Dim custom_fields As New CustomFields()
custom_fields.TextCustomFields.Add(user_id_field)

envDef.CustomFields = custom_fields
```

The custom field is completely absent from the DocuSign XML payload

---

### Last Resort:

I can create an association table that relates DocuSign's `EnvelopeID` GUID to the `user_id` when the envelope is created. I could then use the `EnvelopeID` to look up `user_id` on callback.

---

### My code:

The code below works well. The users receive the documents, sign them, and we receive a callback both when the document is *Sent*, and when the document is *Completed*. The portion that is missing, of course, is passing DocuSign my custom attribute.

*(I've excluded a lot of information like roles, templates, etc, for sake of brevity.)*

```
Dim envDef As New EnvelopeDefinition()

Dim envelope_events As New List(Of EnvelopeEvent)
envelope_events.Add(New EnvelopeEvent("sent", True))
envelope_events.Add(New EnvelopeEvent("completed", True))

Dim recipient_events As New List(Of RecipientEvent)
recipient_events.Add(New RecipientEvent(True, "Sent"))
recipient_events.Add(New RecipientEvent(True, "Completed"))
recipient_events.Add(New RecipientEvent(True, "AuthenticationFailed"))

Dim notification As New EventNotification
' -- Notification properties excluded for brevity --

notification.EnvelopeEvents = envelope_events
notification.RecipientEvents = recipient_events

envDef.EventNotification = notification

Dim apiClient As New ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi")
Dim cfi As New Configuration(apiClient)
Dim authHeader As String = "{""Username"":""" + userName + """, ""Password"":""" + password + """, ""IntegratorKey"":""" + INTEGRATOR_KEY + """}"
cfi.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader)

Dim envelopesApi As New EnvelopesApi(cfi)
Dim envelopeSummary As EnvelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to always create custom fields in Admin Panel. You can specify custom fields dynamically during envelope creation through the API.

The following should work. See the full code [here](https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/a417908601c03f0dab267d9ce9104747#file-createenvelopewithcustomfields-vb-L53-L66).

```
        Dim envDef = New EnvelopeDefinition()
        envDef.EmailSubject = "[DocuSign C# SDK] - Custom Fields"
        envDef.Status = "sent"


        envDef.CustomFields = New CustomFields()

        Dim textCustomField = New TextCustomField()
        textCustomField.Name = "User_Id"
        textCustomField.Value = "KTI456"

        Dim textCustomFields = New List(Of TextCustomField)()
        textCustomFields.Add(textCustomField)
        envDef.CustomFields.TextCustomFields = textCustomFields
```